# Programmaticaly rename a column in Access table after import from Excel

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

Is there a way to programmatically rename the 1st column of a table in Access? Situation: after importing an Excel file into Access, I always need to rename the 1st column which always bears a different column name and manually rename it into **F1**, it would be much easier if this could be done programmaticaly. Is there an easy way to accomplish that using VBA?

Answer (score 2):

Basically open an access application object then you're essentially renaming it as you would within Access vba.

```
Dim appAccess As Access.Application
Set appAccess = New Access.Application
With appAccess
    .OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\...\DatabaseName.accdb"
    .CurrentDb.TableDefs("Table1").Fields(1).Name = "F1"
    .CloseCurrentDatabase
End With
```

Replace `"Table1"` with the name of your table and `.Fields(1)` refers to the first field, `.Fields(2)` refers to the second etc.

Note: Make sure you set your references to Access Object Library (found in Tools > References).  It'll have a name similar to "Microsoft Access 12.0 Object Library"